# Tag popup doesn't show on some tags

Tags: support, tags, popups

I'm having a strange issue with the [[google-analytics] tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) on Web Applications Stack Exchange. When I'm using the latest Firefox on macOS 10.15.5, even with the cache cleared and all userscripts disabled, the tag popup doesn't show. There are no errors in the browser console, the tag does have an excerpt but nothing happens. I'm not able to reproduce it in another browser (or with other tags).

[image]

Comment: Can reproduce on Firefox 76.0.1 x64 Win10. Other tags' hovers appear to work fine, but this one doesn't. Can NOT reproduce on 77.0.1 x64 Win10.

Comment: Glad to hear it's not just me. I do have FF 77.0.1 (but a different OS).

Comment: I just tried it with 2 different browsers (although both using the Chromium engine) with both the page you're viewing, and another one with just that tag, with it working correctly for me. Note I'm using a Windows 10 machine, with it working properly in Microsoft Edge, version 83.0.478.44, and in Chrome 83.0.4103.61. In case it makes any difference, note I'm not currently a member of the Web Applications SE site.

Comment: Works OK for me and I'm on Firefox 77.0.1 on macOS 10.15.5

Comment: I've also tried it with 2 browsers on a Windows 7 machine, using FireFox (76.0.1initially, then upgraded to 77.0.1) and Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61, with it always properly.

Comment: Thanks all. Now it gets officially weird ... pity the SE dev on bug duty ...

Comment: Wait, hold on a minute...I tried this with the dev console open, and it seems like it's due to a bad ad-block filter.

Comment: Good catch Sonic. Glorfindel, what adblocker do you use if any?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog you're right, it's the ad-blocker. Didn't see that coming ... I'm in favor of keeping the [tag:bug] tag as many people use these and it might be an easy fix, but it's perhaps worth posting a workaround or at least an explanation as an answer.

Comment: Just did some more testing and it seems like EasyPrivacy is the filter list to blame. It seems to be detecting an AJAX request to a URL containing `google-analytics` (the tag name in question) and is thus blocking it, preventing the tag popup from working correctly.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Mast Provided an answer.

Comment: Related:‌ [Why can't I see the pop-up card for the adsense tag on hover?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379784/4642212).

Comment: This should be working again. I [suggested a fix](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/pull/5473) to the EasyPrivacy whitelist, and it was approved today. Update your filter lists and try again; it should work now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested this out with the developer console open, and this issue seems to be caused by a bad ad-block filter.

When mousing over the [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics) tag, I got a message in my console that the request to `https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/google-analytics/popup?_=1591253036521` was being blocked by my ad blocker, preventing the tag popup from working correctly.

I disabled one filter list at a time, and found that the filter list to blame is [EasyPrivacy](https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt): that list blocks AJAX requests to anything with `google-analytics` in the URL, and so the request to the tag popup info for that specific tag is being blocked.

I've filed [a report](https://forums.lanik.us/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=44747) on their forum to have this fixed. Hopefully, they'll add this to their allow list.

**Update:** This issue has been fixed. I [proposed a fix](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/pull/5473) to their allow list, and it was just accepted today. Make sure your ad blocker's filter lists are up to date, and it should work now.